# When would I use android.R over my local R.?

Tags: android, r.java-file

If I want to set content view then I use:

```
setContentView(R.layout.test);
```

But when I set a theme, why do I have to add `android` to the beginning of `R.style.x`?

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Light);
setContentView(R.layout.test);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android.R` is a reference to the *Android* R.java file. It is not custom to your app. It contains a reference to every style, resource, anything that you would ever use in an Android app.

On the other hand, `R.x` (without the `android` prefix) refers to your *local* app. It contains specific styles, resources, etc. that have been defined for *your* app, and is much more specific.

So as to your question of which to use:

Use `android.R` if you want to reference a standard style. This would be something like `android.R.style.holo`. It could also be animations, but keep in mind **these are not custom, these are the building blocks**.

Use `R.x` when you are declaring something local. This will be something that *you* have definded, such as `R.style.MyTheme` or `R.layout.MyLayout`.

Answer (score 3):

The android API define a huge amount of standard resources like theme, drawable, attributes, ...

When you need to refer to one of those resources : you must use `android.R`

Answer (score 0):

You are not forced to use `android.R.style.Theme_Light` you can create your theme and use `R.style.myTheme`.

You use `android.R.*` when you want to use a layout/image/attribute/etc. already built inside Android without the need to rewrite it again.

You can use `android.R.*` like `R.x` everywhere you want (they are the same thing, the difference that `R.x` is build with your application while `android.R` is already here). You can remake things, but why do more work when Google already did it for you?